# Linked List : Push : please explain why this code is not working

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
    node** head = nullptr;
    
    push(&head,1);
    push(&head,2);
    push(&head,3);

    printlist(&head);

    return 0;
}

void push(node*** head_ptr,int data){
    node* new_node = new node;
    new_node->data = data;
    if(*head_ptr != nullptr){
        node* temp = **head_ptr;
        while(temp != nullptr){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new_node;
    }
    else{
        *head_ptr = &new_node;
    }
}
```

Whenever `node* new_node = new node;` executes it overwrites head_ptr or head.
Is it because new is allocating same memory block everytime?

Comment: Oh my, a [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)... At least one of the problem is that you assign address of local variable to pointer here: `*head_ptr = &new_node;`, and that local variable dies as soon as the function finishes.

Comment: What is `node`? Please [edit] and show a [mcve] including `printlist`. Also three levels of indirection are most likely not needed.

Comment: An aside: pointers are contextually convertible to `bool`, so you can write `if (*head_ptr)` and `while(temp)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign the address of a local variable, and then use that value after the function has returned, which means your program's behaviour is undefined.

> `*head_ptr = &new_node;`

Having fixed that, you dereference a null pointer, which means your program's behaviour is still undefined.

> ```
> node* temp = *head_ptr;
> while(temp != nullptr){
>    temp = temp->next;
> }
> temp->next = new_node; // you have just looped until temp is null
> ```

You don't need `***`. You shouldn't use `**`. If you want to modify something, pass it by reference, not pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node {
    int data;
    node * next;
};

void printlist(node* n) {
    for (; n; n = n->next) {
        std::cout << n->data;
    }
}

void push(node*& head,int data){
    node* new_node = new node{ data, nullptr };
    if(head != nullptr){
        node* temp = head;
        while(temp->next != nullptr){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new_node;
    }
    else{
        head = new_node;
    }
}

int main(){
    node* head = nullptr;
    
    push(head,1);
    push(head,2);
    push(head,3);

    printlist(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,it was really helpful, Just curious, how can i do ""head = new_node;"" (as you explain in your code) with 3 star pointer.

Comment: `**head = new_node;` You need to assign the pointer-to-node value you got from `new`

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

1. There is one level of indirection too much. You return the *pointer* to `new_node` but you need to return `new_node` itself. Once the function has ended, the local variable `new_node` doesn't exist anymore.
2. You need to initialize the `next` pointer to `nullptr` somewhere. I'm not sure if you did this, because you didn't post all of your relevant code.
3. `while (temp != nullptr)` is wrong, once the loop has ended, `temp` is obviously `nullptr` but you want the last element of the list. You need `while (temp->next != nullptr)`.

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  node* next = nullptr;                  // initialize next to nullptr
};

void push(node** head_ptr, int data) {   // only 2 stars
  node* new_node = new node;
  new_node->data = data;

  if (*head_ptr != nullptr) {
    node* temp = *head_ptr;
    while (temp->next != nullptr) {      // use temp->next instead of temp
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = new_node; 
  }
  else {
    *head_ptr = new_node;                // return new_node instead of a pointer
  }                                      // to new_node
}

int main() {
  node* head = nullptr;

  push(&head, 1);
  push(&head, 2);
  push(&head, 3);

  printlist(&head);                      // you didn't show printlist
                                         // so there might be problems there too
  return 0;
}
```

**Bonuses:**

1. Your code is very inefficient, because for each push you need to find the end of the list which is becoming slower and slower as the list grows. Hint: google *schlemiel the painter*.
2. There is room for further improvements, for example having a constructor for `node` and passing `head` as reference rather than as pointer to a pointer.